# How to transfer a plugin between sites on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a plugin on a sample Wordpress project and I want to transfer it as it is to another Wordpress site of mine. How might that be possible? I have searched the database and found the entries about the plugins, but I have seen that there might be mutliple entries for each plugin folder.

Which is the way to go?

Is it possible to download (already installed) plugins from a live website?

Answer (score 0):

Just ftp the required plugin's folder to your pc, then ftp that folder to the destination server. Then go to Wordpress plugins and activate it.

Comment: In other words, yes you can download plugins from a live website.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload that plugin folder directly at your server using ftp, also you can upload from admin side using zip.